# In this 1979 ACDC concert Angus' guitar seems unplugged

Tags: guitar

Is he miming, playing along to a backing track? Or ifhe is playing, how can that be?

Comment: I was in the middle of posting an answer when this was closed. I don't rembmer where I first heard this but, Angus Young was an early adopter of wireless and apparently liked the tone the early ones produced even using it during studio recording. http://www.voodooguitar.net/2016/10/angus-youngs-secret-wireless-weapon.html

Comment: Nabulio - please in future write questions. I have edited this one for you so it could be reopened. @MichaelCurtis - please feel free to leave an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Wireless radio transmitter, attached to the strap or on his body somewhere. At the other end is a receiver plugged into his amp on stage.

Random Google of a range from a music store...   https://www.gear4music.com/Electric_Guitar/Wireless.html

Equally random image of both halves of an example...

[image]

The systems available in 1979 had a rather unfortunate issue of being very near the same frequencies used by taxi companies to call their drivers.
It was a fairly common interruption in those days, halfway through your best solo effort.. "Car 39, come in. Car 39, can you do a pick up at the airport?"

Comment: Back in those days, it wasn't even necessary to use a system like this. I was on first name terms with a taxi driver at one venue we did often...

Comment: MM desks were known for that... shielding was... ermm... approximate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I first heard this but, Angus Young was an early adopter of wireless and apparently liked the tone the early ones produced even using it during studio recording.

This page has a overview:

http://www.voodooguitar.net/2016/10/angus-youngs-secret-wireless-weapon.html